# Capistrano Deploy Fails To Find Github Repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano

Trying to deploy a Rails App on AWS I get the following error once I try `bundle exec cap production deploy`

```
00:01 git:update
      01 git remote set-url origin git@github.com:AskBid/delegations-explorer-backend.git
    ✔ 01 deploy_user@ec2-x-x-x-x.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 0.066s
      02 git remote update --prune
      02 Fetching origin
    ✔ 02 deploy_user@ec2-x-x-x-x.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 1.148s
00:03 git:create_release
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/delegations-explorer-backend/releases/20201229124628
    ✔ 01 deploy_user@ec2-x-x-x-x.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 0.065s
      02 git archive master | /usr/bin/env tar -x -f - -C /var/www/delegations-explorer-backend/releases/20201229124628
      02 fatal: Not a valid object name
      02 tar:
      02 This does not look like a tar archive
      02
      02 tar:
      02 Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
      02
```

I found many similar problems online and the solution has always been that they didn't push the repository on GitHub or the Repository didn't exist.

In my case the Repo is there.. so I have no clue how to fix this.

this is my `deploy.rb`

```
set :application, "delegations-explorer-backend"
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:AskBid/delegations-explorer-backend.git"
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.6.3'
set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true
```

Comment: Can you post a few lines before the error message?
Are you able to login to your server an manually run `git archive master`?

Comment: I have added the information (lines), where should I run `git archive master` exactly? I tried in the folder where the repo should go on the server but I get `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, capistrano deploys the `master` branch. But your repository contains only a `main` branch.

Just configure capistrano to deploy from the `main` branch.

```rb
set :branch, "main"
```